# How can I change this function from an InputBox to a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the Testing() function to utilize a UserForm instead of an application inputbox. I've already made the UserForm with a Username and Password input, and a "Login" button, but I'm not sure what the code for Login button on the form needs to look like.

I've included the Login function that it references and the relevant declarations.

```
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim User As String
    Dim Pass As String
    User = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Username")
    Pass = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Password")
    Const AccountID = "Cerberus"
    Dim Cerberus As New Class_Cerberus
    Call Cerberus.Login(AccountID, User, Pass)

    Range("A1") = Cerberus.GUID

    Set Cerberus = Nothing

End Sub
```

```
Private Online_ As Boolean
Private Username_ As String
Private Password_ As String
Private AccountID_ As String
Private GUID_ As String
Private GUID_Timestamp As Date

Public Function Login(Optional ByRef AccountID As String, Optional ByRef Username As String, Optional ByRef Password As String) As Boolean
    If Not Online_ Then 'Verify connectivity before proceeding
        If Not CheckOnline Then Exit Function
    End If
    'If any credentials are given at this time, store them for later use and proceed with login
    If Not IsMissing(AccountID) Then AccountID_ = AccountID
    If Not IsMissing(Username) Then Username_ = Username
    If Not IsMissing(Password) Then Password_ = Password

    If Not (Len(GUID_) = 0 Or GUID_Timestamp < (Now() - TimeSerial(8, 0, 0))) Then Login = True
    Dim RawJSON As String: RawJSON = GetHTTP(BASE_URL & "?fct=login&accountid=" & AccountID_ & "&username=" & Username_ & "&password=" & Password_ & "&browserinfo=NULL&format=JSON")
    Dim JSON As Object: Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(RawJSON)

    Login = JSON("status") = "ok"
    GUID_ = JSON("results")(1)("GUID")
    GUID_Timestamp = GetDateTime(JSON("results")(1)("DATE_ALIVE"))
    Set JSON = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Your userform code would be pretty much the same except you'd reference your textbox controls instead of `InputBox`  You'd probably also want to check the return value from `Login` to see whether or not it was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your Login Button will be a `CommandButton` which you can drag over from the `Toolbox`.

[image]

You said you already made the User/Pass Input box so the `CommandButton` code would be something like this.

```
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim User As String
    Dim Pass As String
    User = TextBox1.Value 'Changed from Application.InputBox("Enter Your Username")
    Pass = TextBox2.Value
    Const AccountID = "Cerberus"
    Dim Cerberus As New Class_Cerberus
    Call Cerberus.Login(AccountID, User, Pass)

    Range("A1") = Cerberus.GUID

    Set Cerberus = Nothing

    Unload Me 'This closes the Userform, perhaps add a check If Login = True then Unload Me

End Sub
```

Note: You can hide PWD via the Property of the Input Field via `PasswordChar = *`.

[image]